# How do I pass arguments that you are able to iterate through in a makefile?

Tags: loops, makefile, command-line

I have this in my makefile:

```
test_x_number_times:
for time in `seq $(TIMES)` ; do \
    for dc in $(DCs) ; do \
        echo $$dc ; \
            poetry run kit test -d $$dc --testcase-id=$(TESTCASES) || true ; \
    done ; \
done ;
```

and want to be able to pass multiple values in for `TESTCASES` and `DCs` so that I can iterate through them in a for loop, but I don't know how to list out the arguments on the command line in a way that it sees the values as values you can iterate through. Here is what I have tried:

1. make make test_x_number_times TIMES=1 DCs=B1,G1 TESTCASES=1,2
2. make make test_x_number_times TIMES=1 DCs=B1 G1 TESTCASES=1 2
3. make make test_x_number_times TIMES=1 DCs=(B1 G1) TESTCASES=(1 2)

How do I do this? I can't find it anywhere in documentation or stackoverflow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The shell `for` loop expects to see whitespace-separated words to iterate on.  To pass whitespace in a single shell argument you need to quote it:

```
make make test_x_number_times TIMES=1 DCs='B1 G1' TESTCASES='1 2'
```